# I am getting AttributeError: module 'app' has no attribute 'helpers' when running Djanog runserver on Linux VM

Tags: django, digital-ocean, django-deployment

I am getting AttributeError: module "app" has no attributes 'helpers' when I am trying to import as follow  in HlperConnector.py:

`import app.Helpers.SubHelper as shelpr`

Same setup works perfectly on my VSCode but when deploying on Digital Ocen Linux VM (Ubantu 18.04.3 version).
Here is my directory structure:

```
├───app
│   │   admin.py
│   │   apps.py
│   │   forms.py
│   │   tests.py
│   │   urls.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   ├───Helpers
│   │   │   helper1.py
│   │   │   HelperConnector.py
│   │   │   helper2.py
│   │   │   __init__.py
│   │   ├───SubHelper
│   │   │   │   subhelpers1.py
│   │   │   │   subhelpers2.py
│   │   │   │   __init__.py
└───Project
    │   asgi.py
    │   dosettings.py
    │   settings.py
    │   urls.py
    │   wsgi.py
    │   __init__.py
    │
```

Can someone please help me to resolve the above issue?

I check the Django version which i use for my development (windows PC) is 3.0.6 and Production environment (Ubantu 18.04) is 3.0.7.  But my guess is that this should not be an issue.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

First, You should add below code in app.**ini**.py

default_app_config = 'app.apps.AppConfig'

and, then add this code in app.apps.py

from django.apps import AppConfig

class AppConfig(AppConfig):
name = 'app'

then, import will work.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) about how to format code. Thanks for contributing an answer but can you also add an explanation on how it solves the issue?